# Getting row and column values from 81-element indexed array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an indexed JavaScript array which contains exactly 81 element. These elements will create 9x9 grid (similar to the Sudoku), but for now I need to find the way, how to efficiently get row and column values from that array.

For example, function `getRow(2)` have to return indexed array of 9 values, placed in the second row of the 81-element array, and the `getColumn(2)` have to work by analogy.

Currently my `getRow()` function looks like this:

```
function getRow(rowId){

    // Indexes for every row in the 81-element array
    var rowIndexes = {
        1: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        2: [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17],
        3: [18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26],
        4: [27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35],
        5: [36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44],
        6: [45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53],
        7: [54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62],
        8: [63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71],
        9: [72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80]
    };

    // New array for row values
    var rowValues = new Array();

    for(var i=0; i < 9; i++){
        // Getting row value from 81-element array
        rowValues.push(GRID_ARRAY[rowIndexes[rowId][i]]);
    }

    return rowValues;

}
```

So, is there more dynamic and more optimal method how calculate both row and column values according to the specified row/column ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help! So, finally I got such solution:

```
function getRow(row){

    var rowValues = [];

    for(var i = 9 * (row - 1); i < 9*row; i++){
        rowValues.push(GRID_ARRAY[i]);
    }

    return rowValues;

}


function getColumn(column){

    var columnValues = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        columnValues.push(GRID_ARRAY[i * 9 + (column - 1)]);
    }

    return columnValues;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `row` and `column` are both between 0 and 8, you can calculate the index directly using the formula

```
index = row * 9 + column
```

Comment: Combine that with the `.slice()` method and you can return a whole row with one line of code. (Of course, columns are more complicated.)

Answer (score 0):

do the same thing for getColumn(colId), except for

```
for(var i=0; i < 9; i++){
    // Getting column value from 81-element array
    colValues.push(GRID_ARRAY[rowIndexes[i][colId]]);
}
return colValues;
```